# how to send attachment with uuencode?

Tags: unix, uuencode

I am trying to send an attachment with uuencode, but I do not receive anything in my inbox:

```
uuencode test.txt test.txt | mail -s "test" test@gmail.com
```

I just get a response saying: "You have new mail in /var/mail/user

Does anyone know how to correct this? I too realize that uuencode might not be used as much now, so if anybody could recommend sending attachments another way, it would be much appreciated.

Perhaps it is not recognizing the txt file input?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it looks correct. check logs what is really happen after sending. If you get anything, then it looks more than mail server error.

also if you do get something, but not the attachment-then problem would be in MUA - e.g. program you are using to read emails. Some of them get smart and remove the uu part, but not smart enought to add it as attachment.

mailx should show the uu part unchanged.

UPDATE

for alternative chech this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102092/mail-send-email-with-attachment-from-commandline